# "puede hacer con nosotros" / "puede nos hacer". Are both forms correct in Spanish?

Tags: gramática

In Portuguese we can use any of the sentences below literally translated. They are both correct and have the same meaning.

Does the same apply to Spanish?

Both sentences were created by me so maybe they don't make any sense at all, but here they are anyway:

> Yo sé lo que el exceso de comida chatarra **puede hacer con
> nosotros**.
>
> Yo sé lo que el exceso de comida chatarra **puede nos hacer**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Spanish the unstressed pronouns (like *nos*) cannot be placed between a modal verb and an infinitive in constructions like *poder* + verb, as in Portuguese. They follow the same rules as with single verbs: they have to be placed **before** a conjugated verb, or **after** an infinitive or gerund. In this case it could be either *"nos puede hacer"* or *"puede hacernos"*.

The alternative (*"...puede hacer con nosotros"*) is grammatically correct but it sounds a bit forced.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. And just to be sure I fully understood it, I can use any of the constructions below:

Yo sé lo que el exceso de comida chatarra nos puede hacer.

Yo sé lo que el exceso de comida chatarra puede hacernos.

Is that correct?

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: @Itamar note you probably want _comida basura_ not _comida chatarra_

Comment: *Comida chatarra* is common around here, actually. Obviously a literal translation from the English, but it's what we use.

Comment: For any still in doubt, see [**_chatarra_**](https://tureng.com/en/spanish-english/chatarra) and [**_comida chatarra_**](https://tureng.com/en/spanish-english/comida%20chatarra).  Gracias, pablodf76.  No sabía eso.